# C# - Abstract class extends class and new()?

Tags: c#

In some existing piece of code i see the following:

```
public abstract class BasicComponent<T> : IBasicComponent<T> 
                                          where T : class, new()
```

I know what an abstract class is, and an interface. But what is it doing with `where T` and what happends when you extends `class` and `new()`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These are [generic type constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx).

The `class` means that the `T` you use must be a class (including interface, delegate and arrays), the `new` that it must have a public parameterless constructor.

From the linked MSDN document:

> where T : class - 
>   The type argument must be a reference type; this applies also to any class, interface, delegate, or array type.
>
> where T : new() - The type argument must have a public parameterless constructor. When used together with other constraints, the new() constraint must be specified last.

Answer (score 1):

`where T` restricts the generic type T

`class` means T must be a class and no struct or value type
`new` means T has to have parameterless constructor

Answer (score 1):

**`Where`** is used to declare constraints on the generic type parameter, which in turn means the compiler can allow some things it could not otherwise because it doesn't know enough about the type parameter.

```
where T : class;
```

**This restricts the type parameter `T` to be a `class`** - *this means that this method will only accept it as `class` and not as a value type or struct.*

```
where T : new();
```

**This restricts the type parameter `T` to be a type which has a parameterless constructor** defined. *The compiler can thus accept the following:*

```
T t = new T();
```

Answer (score 1):

It says that `T` must be a reference type (`class`) and must have a parameterless constructor `new()`.

This means that `BasicComponent<T>` and classes derived from it can do things that can only be done in such contexts. It also means they can do things that are pointless otherwise. Conversely, if we don't have it.

```
public abstract class BasicComponent<T>
{
  public T Build()
  {
    return new T();//can't do this without `new()` constraint.
  }
  public bool Check(T item)
  {
    return item != null;//only references types can be null, so 
                        //can't do this without `class` constraint
                        //though notice that `default(T)` works for
                        //both reference and value types.
  }
  public bool IsSame(T x, T y)
  {
    return ReferenceEquals(x, y);//pointless with value-types.
                                 //x and y would be passed to IsSame by
                                 //copying, then boxed to two different objects
                                 //then this will always return false.
                                 //as part of a generic implementation that
                                 //accepted both value and reference types
                                 //it might be that we still care to do something
                                 //for reference-equals, in other cases the 
                                 //pointlessness would make the whole class pointless
                                 //for value types.
  }
  public abstract void Whatever();//just added in so the class still does something abstractly!
}
```

Note that a class derived from `BasicComponent<T>` must be at least as strict - it must have every constraint that `BasicComponent<T>` has, and may or may not add further constraints of its own.

Answer (score 0):

T is the generic part where you are going to use.
Where is a keyword acts like a filter (similar to other languages)

Here you have used, class and new()

which means,

 you can use any class to be passed in this generic class.

 new() means, you are telling the class that it will have parameter less constructor.